# Can an Azure Worker Role run as a logged in user?

Tags: azure, ms-office, azure-worker-roles, office-automation

We are doing some word automation ([that should never be done from any server context](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)) We are busy writing replacement code, but in the mean time I was wondering whether it is possible to run the worker role task as a specific logged in user. (As word does not like being automated from service accounts)

Comment: How would a user "log in" to a worker role? Remote Desktop? No, you cannot run the role code itself from a predefined account, but you can extract some of the code into a separate process and run that under any account.

Comment: @sharptooth You should add the above comment as the answer, as well as a link to how one would go about extracting some code and running under any account